# Negating prefixes in implied repetition of adjective

Tags: double-negation, negative-prefixes

> Although his argument is incorrect, his grammar is [not].

Here, my intuition says we need the "not" to form the double negative "not incorrect". But a person I'm arguing with wants to remove it, interpreting "incorrect" as functionally equivalent to "not correct" and so negating the "in-" in the second clause.

Of course there are other options, like "his grammar is correct, though his argument is not", but I would like to know if it's common to view negating prefixes as grammatical elements like this. And what's the name for this construction where the adjective is implied repeated in a second clause?

Comment: I don't think many people would regard your friend's version as acceptable. Your own version would probably be better if you used some positive adjective for _grammar_, such as _faultless_, rather than  _not [incorrect]_.

Comment: 'Although his dog is insane, his cat is not.' 'Peter is infirm, but his wife is not.' Perhaps some examples of negating prefixes are less in-your-face than others.